# php Invalid argument supplied for foreach();

Tags: php, mysql

Есть скрипт, который пингует все IP адреса в столбце "ip_address". Нужно чтобы после пинга записывались результат в столбец "status". Т.е. если компьютер находится онлайн, в столбец "status" писать значение 1, а если оффлайн - 0. Пример базы: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой скрипт:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("192.168.10.56", "test", "test", "test");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Работает: Подключение с базой данных имеется!" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Информация о хосте: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

foreach($devices as $value){
    exec("ping -c 1 " . $value->ip_address, $output, $result);
    if ($result == 0) {
        $insert_sql = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE 'test' SET 'status'='1' WHERE ip_addres = '".$value->ip_address."'");
     }else{ 
        $insert_sql = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE 'test' SET 'status'='0' WHERE ip_addres = '".$value->ip_address."'");
}
    }

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Меня удивляет то, что, когда я запускаю скрипт в самом сервере, он не показывает никаких ошибок, но и не пишет в столбец. Но когда запускаю его на виртуальном сервере, то вот что:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `$devices` - это список IP адресов? покажите его структуру, пожалуйста. Откуда вы его берете?

Comment: мои боги. Php вообще учили? Читайте хотя бы мануал http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php

Comment: что хочешь этим сказать? Вроде мы делаем всё правильно... или нет?

Answer (score 5):

Вообще-то правильно он все пишет.

`Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` - он ссылается на строку `foreach($devices as $value)`. Судя по коду, переменная `$devices` нигде не создается, вот он ее и не видит.

Предположим, что `$devices` это массив с IP адресами.
В таком случае Ваш код будет выглядить вот так:

```
// берем из таблицы список ip адресов (тут можно и WHERE добавить)
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT ip_address FROM devices");
if ($result) { // если список есть
    $ok = $bad = Array(); // в этих массивах будем хранить списки адресов после проверки
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // прокручиваемся через него по одному
        exec("ping -c 1 " . $row["ip_address"], $output, $result); // пингуем адрес
        if ($result == 0) { // в зависимости от результатов пинга заносим адрес в массив
            $ok[] = $row["ip_address"];
        } else { 
            $bad[] = $row["ip_address"];
        }
    }
    // если есть OK адреса - обновлем все сразу одним запросом
    if (Count($ok)) {
        mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE test SET `status`=1 WHERE `ip_address` IN ('".implode("', '", $ok)."')");
    }
    // если есть BAD адреса - обновлем все сразу одним запросом
    if (Count($bad)) {
        mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE test SET `status`=0 WHERE `ip_address` IN ('".implode("', '", $bad)."')");
    }
}
```

---

А если Вас удивляет то, что ошибки показываются на одном сервере и не показываются на другом, так это вполне могут быть просто настройки. Отключено показывание сообщений об ошибках.
Поставьте вот это

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

в первых строчках кода. И тогда ошибки будут отображаться везде.

Comment: так я попробывал `foreach($devices as $value)` и так, `foreach($test as $value)` , даже так `foreach($test => $devices as $value)`... а ошибка не меняется... не могли подсказать как надо? чтобы он работал, а то 3 день как мучаюсь :(

Comment: нет-нет, синтакс у Вас правильный. Система просто на знает, что такое `$devices`. У Вас нигде этого в коде нет.

Comment: а как его объявлять? О.о  Я ещё новичок в php, а то что я базами данных указал test ничего не меняет?

Comment: @TriSTaR foreach это последовательный обход коллекции, я так понимаю у Вас есть список "устройств" который Вы хотите пропинговать, я Вас правильно понял?! если да то создайте массив/список и заполните его необходимыми данными, например ip адресами, а дальше у Вас уже все есть

Comment: Да! на скрине не достаточно показано но есть столбец **ip_address** где хранятся все айпи адреса всех пользователей кто присоединён к нашим сетям, так вот я хотел бы пинговать каждые 3 мин. (автоматически) и узнавать они в сети или нет!

Comment: ааааааааааааа, так `devices` это имя таблицы? :) ясно... ща исправим ответ...

Comment: Даа)) вот сама база http://i.stack.imgur.com/t0PVc.jpg

Comment: обновил ответ, посмотрите. Обратите внимание, что у Вас в `UPDATE` запросе неверно написано поле `ip_addres`. Должно быть `ip_adress`.

Comment: Чётко и с подсказкой... Спасибо :))) Сейчас попробую ваш скрипт запустить... И да прошу прошение за грубые ошибки, просто русский не родной язык

Comment: не страшно, тут модераторы грамотные.... исправим :) - мне ядерная физика тоже не родная ;)

Comment: `Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in Z:\home\netmap.uz\www\fizkorpus1.php on line 21`
нашёл ошибку в `$result = mysql_query("SELECT ip_address FROM devices WHERE test", $link);`

Comment: а что такое `WHERE test`? в таблице `devices` у Вас нет такой колонки. `SELECT ip_address FROM devices` вытащит все адреса из таблицы...

Comment: `Where test` убрал, ошибка остаётся :(

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6BQRR.jpg 
Может я где-то делаю не так?

Comment: попробуйте поменять `mysql_query` на `mysqli_query` и `mysql_fetch_array` на `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: не получилось,    `Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in Z:\home\netmap.uz\www\fizkorpus1.php on line 21`

Comment: поменял место $link в начало в `mysqli_query` ошибка поменялось, на `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, integer given in Z:\home\netmap.uz\www\fizkorpus1.php on line 24`

Comment: да только что я это написал, сам и думал может $link местами поменять

Comment: идем дальше... строка 24 - поставьте `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {`

Comment: ничего не поменялось, ошибка не меняется...

Comment: странно все это... попробуй поставить обратно `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {`

Comment: `Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in Z:\home\netmap.uz\www\fizkorpus1.php on line 24`
нет.. наверное **"Ну и запросики у вас!" - сказала база данных и не хочет работать..** :D

Comment: :( слушай, мне уже пора идти - не могу задержаться. Но главное, это команды БД правильно подобрать. Мы с тобой все делали вобщем-то правильно (http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php). Просто где-то какая-то мелочь ускользает. Поищи. Убедись, что `$result` содержит данные, не пустой... И чтобы `$row` в конце концов оказалось ассоциативным массивом, чтобы `$row["ip_address"]` сработало. Извини, я должен уйти. Вернусь через несколько часов. Не разберешься - продолжим. Удачи.

Comment: Окей, спасибо большое что уделил своё время... Попытаюсь найти в чём загвоздка

Comment: Ну что, разобрался? заработало?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30628/discussion-on-answer-by-cyadvert-php-invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach).